# Any easy method to clone object to subclass?

Tags: java, swing, clone, instance

Question: Is there any way to instance `FocusInEvent` from`FocuseEvent` ? Because I have several events like this.(e.g. MouseClickedEvent from MouseEvent, KeyPressedEvent from KeyEvent)

Subclass like:

```
interface SwingExtendEvent
{}
class FocusInEvent extends FocusEvent implements SwingExtendEvent
{

    public FocusInEvent(Component source, int id, boolean temporary,
            Component opposite)
    {
        super(source, id, temporary, opposite);
    }
}
class FocusOutEvent extends FocusEvent implements SwingExtendEvent
{

    public FocusOutEvent(Component source, int id, boolean temporary,
            Component opposite)
    {
        super(source, id, temporary, opposite);
    }
}
```

My solution:

```
public static <T extends FocusEvent & SwingExtendEvent> T event(Class<T> eventClass, FocusEvent e)
{
    Constructor<T> constructor;
    T o = null;
    try
    {
        // Constructor
        // (Component source, int id, boolean temporary,
        // Component opposite)
        constructor = eventClass.getConstructor(Component.class, int.class,boolean.class,
                Component.class);
        o = (T) constructor.newInstance(
                e.getComponent(), e.getID(), e.isTemporary()
                , e.getOppositeComponent());
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // 这里不应该出现异常 因为 实现的 类 都必须实现该构造函数 
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return o;
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm writing a Swing event adapter.A listener handle all event, then post to a guava EventBus.

A part of my listener

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)
{
    Events.trigger( emitter, e);
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    Events.trigger( emitter, SwingEvents.event(MouseDraggedEvent.class, e));
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    Events.trigger( emitter, SwingEvents.event(MouseEnteredEvent.class, e));
}
```

So I can handle each event by

```
Events.on(component, new Function<MouseEnteredEvent, Void>()
{
    public Void apply(MouseEnteredEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Mouse Entered");
        return null;
    }
});
```

BTW,`Events.on,Events.trigger` is my util function.

Comment: Use a copy constructor?

Comment: Curious why you need this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand things, what you want to do is control the object instantiation. Therefore, I would check the respective creational patterns of [factory method](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) and [abstract factory](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

If you think a mapper could suit for you, you could check the [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) project.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks, I think what I need is a mapper.

Comment: Check the Dozer project. The link is in my edited anser.